# почему не работает функция def process_friend(name, query): выдает None

Tags: python, строки, функции

```
DATABASE = {
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}

# Новая функция, она возвращает правильное словосочетание, склоняя слово "друзья" 
# в зависимости от того, какое число передано в аргументе friends_count
def format_friends_count(friends_count):
    if friends_count == 1:
        return '1 друг'
    elif 2 <= friends_count <= 4:
        return f'{friends_count} друга'
    else:
        return f'{friends_count} друзей'


def process_anfisa(query):
    if query == 'сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(DATABASE)
        # Вызовите функцию format_friends_count() и передайте в неё count.
        # Отредактируйте строку ниже: в ней должно использоваться выражение, 
        # которое вернёт функция format_friends_count()
        format_friends_count(count)
        return f'У тебя {format_friends_count(count)}.'
    elif query == 'кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ', '.join(DATABASE)
        return f'Твои друзья: {friends_string}'
    elif query == 'где все мои друзья?':
        unique_cities = set(DATABASE.values())
        cities_string = ', '.join(unique_cities)
        return f'Твои друзья в городах: {cities_string}'
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'
def process_query(query):
    elements  = query.split(', ')
    if elements[0]=='Анфиса':
        process_anfisa(elements[1])    
        return process_anfisa(elements[1])
    else:
        process_friend(elements[0], elements[1])

     '''   
def process_friend(name, query):
    if name in DATABASE:
        if query == 'ты где?':
            city = DATABASE[name]
            return f'{name} в городе {city}'  # тут строка "имя_друга в городе 
название_города"
        else:
            return '<неизвестный запрос>'
    else:
        return f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'    

    '''

print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
print(process_query('Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, где все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто виноват?'))
print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
print(process_query('Коля, что делать?'))
print(process_query('Антон, ты где?'))
```

Comment: 1) Это просто функция `process_friend`, без всякого `def`. 2) Она работает, полагаю, но вы ничего неё не принимаете в вызывающей функции. Почитайте про функции, их вызов и работу с возвращаемыми значениями.

Comment: Спасибо! Как раз про return я и не допоняла, все стало работать!

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто, вы забыли **return** в строке, где вызываете функцию process_friend. Поэтому и возвращается None (В том смысле, что ничего не возвращается).

Comment: 1) это не тянет на ответ по объему.

Comment: Спасибо! Все дело в return

Comment: Почему не нужен? Я имел в виду строку в функции process_query после else, где вызов функции process_friend. Ведь сначала вызываентся функция process_query, которая вызывает функцию process_friend, возвращающую значение не в print а в функцию, где был вызов. А так как нет return перед вызовом функции, соответсвенно результат никуда и не идёт. Можете сами попробовать.

Comment: @Светлана Отметьте ответ как принятый, если всё ок.

Comment: @Alpensin, у меня комментарий за 5 минут до размещения этого ответа с тем же выводом был с большим объёмом текста:-) Вот Светлана на комментарий и отозвалась. Ответ явно должен быть более развернутым.

Comment: KupA, да, я удалил часть про `return`, сразу как написал, вы просто быстро комментарий написали.